# Add wc results as arguments in a pipe

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am experimenting with bash and I have the following:

```
grep 1000 data.txt  | wc | ./create_file
```

I am trying to find all records that include the number 1000, and use word count to calculate number of lines, word count and character count (default of wc).

**Can I somehow add the calculations of wc as arguments for my custom script?**

My script expects the 3 numbers produced by wc as arguments ($1, $2, $3)

I've also tried this but I can't seem to get the arguments individually:

```
grep 1000 data.txt | wc | xargs -I {} ./create_file {}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Must it be exactly `1000` or should lines containing i.e. `10001` be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command substitution:

```
./create_file $(grep 1000 data.txt | wc)
```

`$(command)` is replaced with the output of the command.